# Differentiation involving matrix exponentials

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors

I am having trouble understanding differentiation involving matrix exponentials. Suppose we want to compute the derivative of $e^{-At}\mathbf{f}(t)$, where $A$ is a $2\times 2$ real matrix and
$$
\mathbf{f}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
f_1(t) \\
f_2(t)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Using the product rule, I (naively) thought that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-At}\mathbf{f}(t)\right)=e^{-At}\frac{d\mathbf{f}(t)}{dt}-\mathbf{f}(t)Ae^{-At},
$$
but I noticed that $\mathbf{f}(t)Ae^{-At}$ does not make much sense as $\mathbf{f}(t)\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 1}$ while $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and so multiplication is not well-defined. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put $\mathbf{f}(t)$ on the wrong side, that's all. It is
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-At}\mathbf{f}(t)\right)
=e^{-At}\frac{d\mathbf{f}(t)}{dt} - Ae^{-At}\mathbf{f}(t)
$$

Comment: Thanks you for your response, but I am still a bit confused. The product rule states that $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(u(t)v(t)\right)=u(t)v'(t)+v(t)u'(t).$$ Does your answer assume that $Ae^{-At}\mathbf{f}(t)=\mathbf{f}(t)Ae^{-At}$?

Comment: I would like to point out that this is really the chain rule, which (in this case) looks like the product rule.

Comment: @junjios Do you have any links that you would suggest for me to read?

Comment: The product rule as shown by you holds for one dimensional codomains only. With higher dimensions and matrix multiplication or matrix-vector multiplication, the order of the factors must be kept, for example $\frac{d}{dt}(A(t)B(t)C(t)) = A'(t)B(t)C(t) + A(t)B'(t)C(t)+A(t)B(t)C'(t).$

Comment: @Bell Do you happen to know what Banach spaces are? I can write an explanation in a separate answer, but I need to know about your knowledge first.

Comment: @junjios Yes, I have a general understanding of Banach spaces

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Do you have any links that explain this in more detail?

Comment: @Bell No, I don't. You can derive it directly by expanding the matrix-matrix and matrix-vector multiplications, get the derivatives of the individual components using the ordinary product rules for the one-dimensional case, and compare those with the result of the product rule for matrices/vectors, in which the order of factors is kept. It is tedious, but it might help building a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $A:\mathbb R\to\mathcal{L}(X;Y)$ and $B:\mathbb R\to X$ be continuously differentiable functions. Here, $\mathcal L(X;Y)$ is the Banach space of bounded linear functions from $X$ to $Y$.
So let's define
$$F(t):=A(t)B(t)=A(t)\circ B(t)=A(t,B(t)).$$
Now, we can use the chain rule
$$F'(t)=\partial_t A(t,B(t))+\partial_BA(t,B(t))B'(t).$$
Note: We have $\partial_tA(t,B(t))=A'(t)B(t)$ and since $A(t)$ is a bounded linear map in $B$ for every $t$, its derivative with respect to $B$ is just the linear map itself:
$$\partial_BA(t,B(t))=A(t).$$
Put together we get
$$F'(t)=A'(t)B(t)+A(t)B'(t).$$

So, this does really look like the product rule, although it is not. Note also, how you cannot switch the order of $A$ and $B$, so this is consistent with Reinhard Meier's answer.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!